# using Functions vs using templates in XSLT?

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

What are the pros and cons of functions vs templates in XSLT?

I want to send a unix-timestamp and get an answer like "today" or "tomorrow" or "next week". Which method is most appropriate for this?

Comment: Do you use XSLT 1.0 or 2.0 or what kind of functions do you have in mind if you use XSLT 1.0?

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a complete and simple solution provided by an `<xsl:function>`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main reason of choosing an `<xsl:function>` over a named template is the much greater degree of composability of a function.

**It is very easy and convenient to write an `<xsl:function>` that produces the wanted results**:

```
 <xsl:function name="my:when" as="xs:string">
  <xsl:param name="pDateTime" as="xs:dateTime"/>

  <xsl:sequence select=
  "for $vToday in xs:dateTime(current-date()),
       $vTomorrow in $vToday
                    + xs:dayTimeDuration('P1D'),
       $vDayAfterTomorrow in $vTomorrow
                    + xs:dayTimeDuration('P1D'),
       $vNextWeek in $vToday
                    + 7* xs:dayTimeDuration('P1D'),
       $vNextFortnight in $vNextWeek
                    + 7* xs:dayTimeDuration('P1D')

       return
         if($pDateTime lt $vToday)
           then 'in the Past'
           else if($pDateTime lt $vTomorrow)
             then 'Today'
             else if($pDateTime lt $vDayAfterTomorrow)
              then 'Tomorrow'
             else if($pDateTime lt $vNextWeek)
              then 'This week'
             else if($pDateTime lt $vNextFortnight)
              then 'Next week'
              else 'In the Future'
  "/>
 </xsl:function>
```

**Here is a complete transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
 xmlns:my="my:my">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:sequence select="my:when(current-dateTime())"/>,
  <xsl:sequence select="my:when(current-dateTime()
                               +xs:dayTimeDuration('P1D'))"/>,
  <xsl:sequence select="my:when(current-dateTime()
                               +xs:dayTimeDuration('P2D'))"/>,
  <xsl:sequence select="my:when(current-dateTime()
                               +xs:dayTimeDuration('P3D'))"/>,
  <xsl:sequence select="my:when(current-dateTime()
                               +xs:dayTimeDuration('P4D'))"/>,
  <xsl:sequence select="my:when(current-dateTime()
                               +xs:dayTimeDuration('P5D'))"/>,
  <xsl:sequence select="my:when(current-dateTime()
                               +xs:dayTimeDuration('P6D'))"/>,
  <xsl:sequence select="my:when(current-dateTime()
                               +xs:dayTimeDuration('P7D'))"/>,
  <xsl:sequence select="my:when(current-dateTime()
                               +xs:dayTimeDuration('P8D'))"/>,
  <xsl:sequence select="my:when(current-dateTime()
                               +xs:dayTimeDuration('P9D'))"/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:function name="my:when" as="xs:string">
  <xsl:param name="pDateTime" as="xs:dateTime"/>

  <xsl:sequence select=
  "for $vToday in xs:dateTime(current-date()),
       $vTomorrow in $vToday
                    + xs:dayTimeDuration('P1D'),
       $vDayAfterTomorrow in $vTomorrow
                    + xs:dayTimeDuration('P1D'),
       $vNextWeek in $vToday
                    + 7* xs:dayTimeDuration('P1D'),
       $vNextFortnight in $vNextWeek
                    + 7* xs:dayTimeDuration('P1D')

       return
         if($pDateTime lt $vToday)
           then 'in the Past'
           else if($pDateTime lt $vTomorrow)
             then 'Today'
             else if($pDateTime lt $vDayAfterTomorrow)
              then 'Tomorrow'
             else if($pDateTime lt $vNextWeek)
              then 'This week'
             else if($pDateTime lt $vNextFortnight)
              then 'Next week'
              else 'In the Future'
  "/>
 </xsl:function>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is applied (to any document -- not used), the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
  Today,
  Tomorrow,
  This week,
  This week,
  This week,
  This week,
  This week,
  Next week,
  Next week,
  Next week
```

Comment: +1 Good answer. But this is missing the reazon for choosing `xsl:function` over templates.

Comment: @Alejandro: Yes, I thought this was obvious. :) Now I edited my answer and its first sentence explains the most pressing reason.

Comment: Excellent edit! Remember that most people don't get the declarative paradigm (an even great XSLT developers refuse to consider XSLT as functional language) so the fundamentals notions about function theory (composition, HOF, tail recursion) are not well known.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, an external function is best-suited.

XSLT is best suited for pattern matching and transformation, not computation.

Comment: @Kristoffer Nolgren - They are specifically selected functions that are implemented by XSLT processors and thus are efficient. You _could_ write anything using XSLT as it is Turing complete, but it won't be pretty, easy or efficient.

Comment: Such an answer is not well-founded. It is very easy, natural and convenient to write a simple `<xsl:function>` that computes the wanted result.

Comment: @Oded: You may be interested in getting introduced to XPath 2.0 and XSLT 2.0, so that your understanding of XSLT and its applicability is improved.

Comment: @Dimitre - fair point... I admit that I am stuck in XSLT 1.0... Do you have any pointers regarding good books/websites?

Comment: @Oded: There are two books by Michael Kay on XSLT2.0/XPath 2.0 that I recommend -- they are listed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/339930/any-good-xslt-tutorial-book-blog-site-online/341589#341589